# XSLT select Nodes where sub-string of element value not equal to element value of other nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to CSS and have hit a roadblock. I have a list of image details as shown below.

```
<Files IsList="true">
  <Item>
    <FileSize>97 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_7vxsysv.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>108 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_9cxjbh7.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>109 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_9cxjbh7_Annotated.jpg</Name>
    <Description>(annotated)</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>170 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_omau6bn.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>175 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_omau6bn_Annotated.jpg</Name>
    <Description>(annotated)</Description>
  </Item>
</Files>
```

All images have an original file and some have an annotated copy (identified by the Description and the suffix on the Name).

I need to display all the images (in a table with 3 images to a row), with the logic:

- If there is an annotated copy then show the annotated version only
- If there is no annotated copy show the original.

Desired Outcome is a select statement that results in the following.

```
  <Item>
    <FileSize>97 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_7vxsysv.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>109 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_9cxjbh7_Annotated.jpg</Name>
    <Description>(annotated)</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>175 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_omau6bn_Annotated.jpg</Name>
    <Description>(annotated)</Description>
  </Item>
```

I was trying to loop through all the nodes and use IF statements to determine which was displayed or not, but because I use position() to determine where to start a new row this does not work because not all images are displayed, throwing off the row calculation.

I was thinking that the select needs to be based on a substring of the value of the Name element that is compared to substring of other Name elements.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? -- Hint: this is basically a *grouping* problem.

Comment: You said you want the output as a 3-column table. Presumably this is a html table. But your desired outcome listing is nothing of the sort. So what output do you want? xml? or html 3-column table?

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer there. I am able to handle the table output,I really just need the XML to put into the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you wanted XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0, and it wasnt clear if you wanted a html table output or xml output (you seemed to contradict yourself in that respect), so this may not exactly meet your requirements, but it might be helpful.

This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet ...

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


<xsl:template match="/">
  <hmtl>
    <head>
      <title>Table of items</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:for-each-group
              select="Files/Item[
                (Description eq '(annotated)') or
                 not(
                   for $name in concat( substring-before( Name/text(), '.jpg'), '_Annotated.jpg') return
                     following-sibling::Item[ Name eq $name])]"
              group-by="(position() - 1) idiv 3">
            <tr>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  </hmtl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
  <td>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

... will transform this input document  ...

```
<Files IsList="true">
  <Item>
    <FileSize>97 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_7vxsysv.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>108 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_9cxjbh7.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>109 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_9cxjbh7_Annotated.jpg</Name>
    <Description>(annotated)</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>170 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_omau6bn.jpg</Name>
    <Description>Picture</Description>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <FileSize>175 kb</FileSize>
    <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
    <Name>CR_0_Pc_omau6bn_Annotated.jpg</Name>
    <Description>(annotated)</Description>
  </Item>
</Files>
```

... into this output html page ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<hmtl>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>Table of items</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <Item>
                     <FileSize>97 kb</FileSize>
                     <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
                     <Name>CR_0_Pc_7vxsysv.jpg</Name>
                     <Description>Picture</Description>
                  </Item>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <Item>
                     <FileSize>109 kb</FileSize>
                     <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
                     <Name>CR_0_Pc_9cxjbh7_Annotated.jpg</Name>
                     <Description>(annotated)</Description>
                  </Item>
               </td>
               <td>
                  <Item>
                     <FileSize>175 kb</FileSize>
                     <Type>image/jpeg</Type>
                     <Name>CR_0_Pc_omau6bn_Annotated.jpg</Name>
                     <Description>(annotated)</Description>
                  </Item>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</hmtl>
```

### Design notes

The grouping (`xsl:for-each-group`) is really only there to marshall the output into a 3 column table. The table will be ragged. If you need a regular table to support older browsers, a little extra code on the last row will be required.

Here is what you would add just before the close `</tr>` to make it regular

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to 3 - count(current-group())">
  <td>&#160;</td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XPath expression in the `xsl:for-each-group/@select` does the heavy lifting for this solution. It selects all the `Item` elements which are either annotated or do not have a matching annotated sibling. This is basically what you want to process for output.

---

### Update

Here is an equivalent XSLT 1.0 solution ..

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    extension-element-prefixes="exsl"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="html" doctype-system="" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />    

<xsl:template match="/">
  <hmtl>
    <head>
      <title>Table of items</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <xsl:variable name="Items">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Files/Item" mode="filter-items" />
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($Items)/Item" mode="row" />
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </body>
  </hmtl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[Description='(annotated)']" mode="filter-items">
  <xsl:copy-of select="." />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[Description!='(annotated)']" mode="filter-items">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="concat( substring-before( Name/text(), '.jpg'), '_Annotated.jpg')" />
  <xsl:if test="not( following-sibling::Item[ Name = $name])">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item[1]" mode="row">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::Item[position() &lt;= 2]" mode="cell" />
    <xsl:variable name="empty-cols" select=" 3 - count(. | following-sibling::Item[position() &lt;= 2])" />
    <xsl:for-each select="(//node())[position() &lt;= $empty-cols]">
      <td>&#160;</td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item" mode="row" />

<xsl:template match="Item" mode="cell">
  <td>
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </td>    
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The above assume that your XSLT 1.0 engine supports exslt. Please do note that there is no reason not to upgrade to XSLT 2.0 . If your platform is browser, then you can use Saxon CE to achieve the upgrade. The output table is made regular with [the Piez method](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/muench.html#d9944e300). If this is too inefficient, there are alternatives.

Comment: Hi Sean. This is great, unfortunately I am using XSLT 1.0. The result is exactly what I am after. Are you able to provide an XSLT v1 option. Cheers Derek

Comment: Yes. OP's almost never give unambiguous questions, and so we would never get any where if we didn't make some assumptions. If the assumption is wrong, either it doesn't matter to the OP, or the OP will post a clarification. So @DerekBest , do you want to clarify?

Comment: "*we would never get any where if we didn't make some assumptions.*" I agree. I made an assumption myself, regarding the length of the filename. However, assumption should be stated.

Comment: Happy to clarify. In this case all image will be .jpg. File names are not always 15 characters. My target is not a browser but a document generator that is a bit old - hence the XSLT v1.  I really appreciate your help on this I am leaning a lot going through the different examples.

Answer (score 0):

> - If there is an annotated copy then show the annotated version only
> - If there is no annotated copy show the original.
>
> Desired Outcome is a select statement that results in the following.

You can select the requested items using the following expression:

```
select="Item[Description='(annotated)' or not(key('anno', substring(Name, 1, 15)))]"/>
```

after defining a key so:

```
<xsl:key name="anno" match="Item[Description='(annotated)']" use="substring(Name, 1, 15)" />
```

This assumes all item names are exactly 15 characters long. If this assumption is incorrect, then it gets more complicated.

---

Note that just *selecting* the items will not be enough, since the selected items maintain their original context. In order to make the selected items siblings, you will want to **copy** them into a variable. Here's an example of a complete stylesheet, grouping the selected items into three columns:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:key name="anno" match="Item[Description='(annotated)']" use="substring(Name, 1, 15)" />

<xsl:template match="/Files">
    <xsl:variable name="items">
        <xsl:copy-of select="Item[Description='(annotated)' or not(key('anno', substring(Name, 1, 15)))]"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="cols" select="3" />
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($items)/Item[position() mod $cols = 1]" >
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::Item[position() &lt; $cols]"/>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item">
    <td><img src="{Name}"/></td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I've got to give it to you. Yours is a better XSLT 1.0 solution than mine. Levering keys makes it simpler. You might want to add a little bit more to make it a regular table.